# Facebook Accountkit JAVASCRIPT Implementation

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to implement the facebook accountkit using javascript. I followed the documentation on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/web/integrating. 
AccountKit login form

```
Enter country code (e.g. +1):
<input type="text" id="country_code" />
Enter phone number without spaces (e.g. 444555666):
<input type="text" id="phone_num"/>
<button onclick="phone_btn_onclick();">Login via SMS</button>
Enter email address
<input type="text" id="email"/>
<button onclick="email_btn_onclick();">Login via Email</button>
```

Below is the javascript code on my app

```
<script src="https://sdk.accountkit.com/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
<script>
// initialize Account Kit with CSRF protection
AccountKit_OnInteractive = function(){
AccountKit.init(
  {
    appId:'facebook_app_id', 
    state:"csrf", 
    version:"accountkit_version"
  }
 );
};

// login callback
 function loginCallback(response) {
 console.log(response);
 if (response.status === "PARTIALLY_AUTHENTICATED") {
  document.getElementById("code").value = response.code;
  document.getElementById("csrf_nonce").value = response.state;
  document.getElementById("my_form").submit();
 }
 else if (response.status === "NOT_AUTHENTICATED") {
  // handle authentication failure
 }
 else if (response.status === "BAD_PARAMS") {
  // handle bad parameters
 }
}

// phone form submission handler
 function phone_btn_onclick() {
 var country_code = document.getElementById("country_code").value;
 var ph_num = document.getElementById("phone_num").value;
 AccountKit.login('PHONE', 
  {countryCode: country_code, phoneNumber: ph_num}, // will use default values if this is not specified
  loginCallback);
 }


 // email form submission handler
 function email_btn_onclick() {
 var email_address = document.getElementById("email").value;

 AccountKit.login('EMAIL', {emailAddress: email_address},  loginCallback);
 }
</script>
```

After setting the required values for `appId`, `state` and `version`. I tried filling the form but I was redirecting to account kit page saying 
`we are sorry, something went wrong, try again`

Any help in the implementation will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: what values are you using for `version` and `state` ?

Comment: Also did you try adding your country code to `Country Codes Whitelist` in AccountKit administration panel ?

Comment: The version I specified for the accountKit is v1.0 and the state is just a random number, and also the `Country` is added  in the panel.

Comment: I hope you have also added correct server url in the panel.

Comment: Yes, all i'm getting is `we are sorry, something went wrong` when I fill the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been resolved. On account kit page on facebook developer site, I pointed the `server url` on `web login settings` to all occurrence of the domain i.e http://domain.com, http://www.domain.com including `https` if available. This resolved the problem. THANKS ALL.

Comment: Are you currently using it without the proof?